# How to Form a Row-Complete Latin Square

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

This is one of the descriptions I've seen online:

For any even $n$, say $n = 2m$, a row complete Latin square of order $n$ can be formed by writing down

$$0, 1, 2m - 1, 2, 2m - 2, 3,\ldots, m + 1, m$$

as the first row and then developing subsequent rows by adding $1$ modulo $n$.

I'm not quite clear on how that goes, such as what the difference is between $2m$ and $m$.  $2m$ stands for $n$, does $m$ stand for modulo?  I'd like to see and example with an even number or two, such as $4$, and $6$.

I tried, $2m = 4$

$$0, 1, 3, 2, 2\ldots$$ 
wait, that can't be right.

It should turn out with non repeating sequences, and non recurring pairs between rows.
I can outline the other methods I've found (but don't understand) if this one is not the best.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand your description correctly, for $2m=4$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0&  1&  3&  2\\
    1&  2&  0&  3\\
    2&  3&  1&  0\\
    3&  0&  2&  1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

For $2m=6$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0&  1&  5&  2&  4&  3\\
    1&  2&  0&  3&  5&  4\\
    2&  3&  1&  4&  0&  5\\
    3&  4&  2&  5&  1&  0\\
    4&  5&  3&  0&  2&  1\\
    5&  0&  4&  1&  3&  2
\end{bmatrix}$$

*edit*: In each case, the first row follows the pattern you gave; in subsequent rows, each number is one more than the number above it, but wrapping around at the size of the square (e.g. in the case where $n=2m=6$, after $5$ comes $0$).

Let's look at $n=2m=12$ $(m=6)$ a bit more closely.  The pattern that you gave said:
$$0, 1, 2m - 1, 2, 2m - 2, 3,\ldots, m + 1, m$$

So, the first row is:
$$0, 1, 12 - 1, 2, 12 - 2, 3,\ldots, 6 + 1, 6$$

which is
$$0, 1, 12-1=11, 2, 12-2=10, 3, 12-3=9, 4, 12-4=8, 5, 12-5=6+1=7, 6$$

Now, the second row is:
$$0+1=1, 1+1=2, 11+1=12$$
becomes
$$0, 2+1=3, 9+1=10, 4+1=5, 8+1=9, 5+1=6, 7+1=8, 6+1=7$$

Continuing gives:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    0&  1& 11&  2& 10&  3&  9&  4&  8&  5&  7&  6\\
    1&  2&  0&  3& 11&  4& 10&  5&  9&  6&  8&  7\\
    2&  3&  1&  4&  0&  5& 11&  6& 10&  7&  9&  8\\
    3&  4&  2&  5&  1&  6&  0&  7& 11&  8& 10&  9\\
                   &&&&&\vdots
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It looks like a good result.  An explanation of how it was calculated would be most helpful.

Comment: @op1: I've edited to include more explanation.  Please let me know if it isn't enough.

Answer (score -1):

As I have essentially asked the same question [somewhere else](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/991078), I wanted to share the answer I was given there by [Gage](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171177/gage):

> See here for more information [on row-complete Latin squares] http://personal.maths.surrey.ac.uk/st/H.Bruin/MMath/LatinSquares.html

The reference outlines a fairly straight forward algorithm and I wrote a a quick MATLAB script to build me an order-n square: https://gist.github.com/hcc23/274b76edc3dd82d5de1a